# Use syntax highlighting for cat .gitignore

Tags: git, cat

Is it possible to get syntax highlighting for `.gitignore` files when using `cat`?

#### Update:

Tried `sudo apt-get install python-pygments` as suggested by @rovo but when using comments in the `.gitignore` it stops working.

Sample `.gitignore` (does not work):

```
# JetBrains IDEs
.idea
```

Sample `.gitignore` (works):

```
.idea
```

Comment: What you mean by color coding ? syntax highlighting?

Comment: yes, updated the question

Comment: https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager

Answer (score 2):

Use `pygmentize`, e. g. by defining aliases like `dog` or `pig`!

Add this lines to `~/.bash_aliases` (or perhaps `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias dog='pygmentize -g'
alias pig='pygmentize -g -O style=colorful,linenos=1'
```

Afterwards restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc`.

You might need to install `python-pygments`  package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

Then you can run `dog .gitgnore` or `pig .gitgnore`

> **pygmentize - highlights the input file**
>   Pygments is a generic syntax highlighter for general use in all kinds of software such as forum systems, wikis or other applications that need to prettify source code.

Comment: It is still black/white - is it possible it doesn't work with `zsh`?

Comment: Doesn't work on `bash` either ... I suggest you using `vimcat`: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4325 or the github link I posted on your question ;)

Comment: as the name `.bashrc` says, it's for `bash`, so yes.  Use `.zshrc` instead

Comment: @Ravexina ?! works well for me ...

Comment: Works well with any file except `.gitgnore` ... :/ Don't know why!

Comment: you may want to use `~/.bash_aliases` to put the aliases. It's a pre-defined location used by default `.bashrc` on ubuntu. dog and pig work fine for me. @RoVo good name finding 

Comment: You should try a different formatter, depending of the capability of your terminal like `-f terminal256` for 256 colors or `-f terminal16m` for true colors

Comment: It works until the `.gitignore` file contains comments like this `# some comment`